# Android:Background in styles lets elements disappear

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles

I changed android:background in my style:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#747474</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccentTrans</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccentTrans</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>

</style>
```

And now some elements like my material calendar view seemed to have lot visibility and I can't figure out why.

Here the XML of the Fragment Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context="io.rocketfox.dreamydiary.JournalView">




<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_nothingInList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_NoDreamsHint"
        android:layout_width="167dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39999998"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sheep" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_NoDreamsHint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="No dreams yet"
        android:textColor="@color/splashScreenAction"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_NoDreamsHint" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_calendarPicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mcv_allowClickDaysOutsideCurrentMonth="true"
        app:mcv_arrowColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceDates"
        app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="monday"
        app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceMonth"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/colorAccentTrans"
        app:mcv_tileSize="40dp"
        app:mcv_tileWidth="50dp"
        app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceWeek"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listDreams"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView"
        android:background="@color/background" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_AddDream"
        style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Fab Button is the only visible thing left.

Screenshot of Layout after background change: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNcAY.jpg

Comment: Add Screen shot if possible so we can help.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your style, you should use `android:windowBackground` instead of `android:background`

> `windowBackground` are style properties that are effective only when
>   the style is applied as a theme to an `Activity` or `application` and
>   `android:windowBackground` attribute only supports a reference to
>   another resource.

2. Only `FAB` is showing because the container of `FAB` is a `RelativeLayout` and its `width` and `height` are `match_parent`. That's why it overlapped with your `layout_calendarPicker`.

**Update your layout XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_nothingInList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_NoDreamsHint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39999998"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sheep" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_NoDreamsHint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="No dreams yet"
            android:textColor="@color/splashScreenAction"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img_NoDreamsHint" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_calendarPicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:mcv_allowClickDaysOutsideCurrentMonth="true"
            app:mcv_arrowColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            app:mcv_dateTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceDates"
            app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="monday"
            app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceMonth"
            app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/colorAccentTrans"
            app:mcv_tileSize="40dp"
            app:mcv_tileWidth="50dp"
            app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearanceWeek"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listDreams"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView"
            android:background="@color/background" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_AddDream"
            style="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself: My problem was that between fragment transitions a white background was appearing because of the rendering and the underlying background color.
What I needed to add to the styles was **not**

```
    <item name="android:background">color here</item>
```

Instead I had to edit

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">color here</item>
```

This fixed the issue.